# dynamic library don't generate lib file using visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, window

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I creared dll without using MFC, it generating the dll. But when I specify to generate a lib file in specific directory using the following option:-
go to proeperties page->Advanced->Import Library
../../../lib/myapp.lib

It is not genearting the lib file in the specified folder. Please help me .

Thanks & Regards
Vikas

Answer (score 5):

Just resolved a similar problem. Visual Studio does not create a .lib file without instructing which objects to expose in dll. You need to create a win exports header like this:

```
#ifndef BLABLABLA
#define BLABLABLA

#ifdef MYAPPLIB_EXPORTS
#define MYAPPLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#elif defined(MYAPPLIB_EXPORTS_STATIC)
#define MYAPPLIB_API 
#else
#define MYAPPLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif 

#endif // !BLABLABLA
```

Then, you need to declare MYAPPLIB_EXPORTS as a preprocessor macro. After including this new header file in other API headers,  for every class or method which you want to expose in your API, you can add MYAPPLIB_API to their declarations like:

```
class MYAPPLIB_API MyClass{ ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    calculatelibrary.h
```

/* 
By default, the New Project template for a DLL adds PROJECTNAME_EXPORTS to the defined preprocessor symbols for the DLL project.
 In this example, CALCULATELIBRARY_EXPORTS is defined when your calculateLibrary DLL project is built.
 When the CALCULATELIBRARY_EXPORTS symbol is defined, the CALCULATELIBRARY_API symbol sets the __declspec(dllexport) modifier on the member function declarations in this code. 
 This modifier tells the compiler and linker to export the function or variable from the DLL so that it can be used by other applications.
 When CALCULATELIBRARY_EXPORTS is undefined—for example, when the header file is included by a client application—CALCULATELIBRARY_API defines the __declspec(dllimport) modifier on the member function declarations. This modifier optimizes the import of the function in an application. For more information[image]

*/

```
    #ifndef _calculate_library_h
    #define _calculate_library_h

    #ifdef CALCULATELIBRARY_EXPORTS
    #define CALCULATELIBRARY_API _declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #define CALCULATELIBRARY_API _declspec(dllimport)
    #endif



    namespace calculatelibrary
    {
          class CALCULATELIBRARY_API clsCalculateLibrary{

               // Returns a + b  
              double  Add(double a, double b);  
        };
    }
    #endif _calculate_library_h

    // CalculateLibrary.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "CalculateLibrary.h"


    namespace calculatelibrary
    {

            double clsCalculateLibrary::Add(double a, double b)  
        {  
            return a + b;  
        }  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following: you may need to declare /EXPORTS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k30y2k5.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67wc07b9.aspx  see "REMARKS"